# MVC : Search Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search

I Make Search Function , where Customer can logged in with their CustomerID and than when they logged in , they can Only search after their Order number , so far everything working fine,But When i tried to search after order number or better i say OrderID (for ex: 1111) and than i hit button ,instead show me that order i just searched , it will show all ordersID as you can see in Screenshots,But i dont want that,i want use or include CustomerID Session to show results for that CustomerID just logged in and i tried different thing but its not worked or its not what i want and to be honest idont know how to do it.Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**Search Result** :
[image]

Comment: Your form does not include any forM controls for a property named `OrderID` so its never set (fortunately `new { name = "OrderID" }` does nothing at all - look at the html your generating)

Comment: Would you please tell me, wat should i write instead ?! :)

Comment: You can solve the immediate issue by using `@Html.TextBox("OrderIID)` but this is awful code. Use a view model and strongly bind to your view model.

Comment: Tnx Stephen for help :)